# New Line character with StringReader - \n is ignored?

Tags: java, csv, format, inputstream, stringreader

I have this code:

```
String sampleString = "1223,4455,6667" + "\n" + "1223,4455,6667" + "\n";

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sampleString));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   if (line.trim().length() == 0) {
        continue;
   }
   logger.debug("CSVLIne:" + line);
}
```

I was expecting it to print two lines. But it shows all in one line. Anything wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape those newlines

```
    String sampleString = String.format("1223,4455,6667%n1223,4455,6667%n")
```

The %n format specifier introduces platform dependent newline.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried it myself, and above code prints two lines on my machine when using `System.out.println` for output.

As others have pointed out, "\n" is not platform independent, but according to the [BufferedReader documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29):

> A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed
>   ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed
>   immediately by a linefeed.

it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Its because logger.debug outputs on one line without newlines. If you want to print on two lines you need to use logger.debug twice.

Comment: The OP calls `logger.debug()` inside the loop, so it should be executed twice.